# Consuming asp.net web service from Javascript and Mithril.JS - what is the best method / library for post /get request?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, api, mithril.js

So I have to create client app in Mihtril.JS that will consume ASP.NET webservice.
What i find out, that there is no way to send login request to this web service, and receive access token through mithril.js m.request function. 
I've used then reqwest  library, this give me little success, because i'm now able to receive  access token. 
Problem now is - how to send request to this web service, and receive any data. 
We have tried to set headers with token, or send login details into post request, but server always returning to us 405 error. How to pull data from it?

I don't want to use jQuery $ajax function.

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery's ajax function successfully currently? Anything that's possible with it will be possible with `m.request` (with varying amounts of effort). Unfortunately the issue/question feels a little vague at the moment, but if you're able to indicate what works with jQuery, it might be possible to reverse engineer the appropriate `m.request` equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `m.request` function](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.request.html). [The Mithril guide has a section on web services](http://mithril.js.org/web-services.html) which might be helpful.